# Access 2010 Database - Front ends that do not require web server?

Tags: silverlight, flash, ms-access, charts, ms-access-2010

#### background

I need to be able to display charts that can capture what the user has clicked on. So for a pie chart, if a user clicks on a pie piece, I should be able to capture which piece he selected. Scatter plot should capture what plot, etc. Access-UI can't capture these things, only that a user clicked on the graph. So I need a different solution.

#### problem

We do not have access to a web server. The front end needs to connect directly with the access database. So what front end solutions can I use that will give me the UI flexibility I need to solve my problem?

#### possible solutions?

- Use silverlight in access (http://desktopweb.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-silverlight-with-access-part-ii.html)
- Winforms that connects to Access database via ADO

Is there anything that allows me to use HTML/JS or flash? HTML/JS would be the best solution, followed by flash just due to its wide support. I was researching Web Browser Control but I am not completely clear on whether it is opening local HTML files or browsing through http.  I also wasn't clear if it supports JS or can load Flash.

Answer (score 0):

When you first said about the click though capability my first thought was the reporting that is possible using SSRS. The easiest way is to have a reporting server and have the reports available through a browser. However you say you can’t have a web server so I’m guessing that a reporting server is also out.

You could however still use BIDS or report builder to make your reports and then the report viewer control in a flavour of .net to display the reports. Note that you have to convert them to RDLC files and feed the data to them.

That’s my 2p worth, I won’t comment on flash or silverlight as I don’t know enough about them to make an informed recommendation

Comment: I am not familiar with BIDS, what is that? Is that basically report builder that we can put on top of a .NET application?

Comment: BIDS = Business Intelligence Design Studio. It’s very similar to report builder but is based on visual studio. The end output is basically the same

Answer (score 0):

The web browser control that's usable in Access can use any resource that can be reached via a URL, or you can assign a string of HTML (valid, of course) to it. I forget the exact property you use for the latter, but it's doable (I didn't know this the last time I implemented a web browser control to display HTML from an Access app, so created a temp file, and never went back to replace that with just assigning the HTML directly once I learned how -- so I forgot how, of course!).